# How To Install pyserial for Windows 10 (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, pyserial

I just wanted to know how to install pyserial for python 3.7. I attempted to install pyserial 2.7 but every time it finishes installing, the file cannot be located.

I was just wondering if there's anyway to overcome this issue as i'm going to be writing a program to communicate to a PC via serial comms.

regards,
~Wing

Comment: How are you installing it ? Are you using pip or conda, or are you installing from source ?

Comment: @Zuma it will be through conda3, i wanted to do it through pip but doing it was horrible

Comment: Have you tried running `conda install -c conda-forge pyserial` in command line ? Also what was the error raised when you attempted the install with pip ?

Comment: When i installed pip, i said it installed successfully. So, i open cmd and it said that 'pip' isnt recognised. And i just tried what you said and it didn't recognise it

Comment: Do you have anaconda for windows ? If so cmd should recognize the conda command. Also if you download anaconda you can try to install pyserial directly from the graphic UI which should be easier if you are not used to installing packages from command line

Comment: Yes i manged to get it now. I downloaded it through visual studio and it allowed my to install the 'pyserial' package.